# Per repository AuthzSVNAccessFile apache rule with a single apache config file or other shell script solution

Tags: apache, shell, svn, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am writing a set of svn hooks to allow remote management of the SVN repository, just like gitolite does with GIT.

I created the script that generates the AuthzSVNAccessFile for each repository I have, now I need to tell Apache to look for each of them depending on the repository.

I cannot have a apache config file for each repository, because it would need to restart the apache server.

I know I can use a single AuthzSVNAccessFile to manage multiple repository, but the script that build the file takes time (need to discover the full path of every dir inside the repository), and would make the commit take too long.

I tried to use mod_rewrite, but it did not work, maybe I used it wrong.

Basically I need to have a rule in my apache configuration file that reads different file depending on the URL requested, is that possible? How?

Or I need a script able to rewrite a block of a file. I am using `sed` to replace the strings I have in my template, but do not know how to use it to replace multiple lines.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea why you're trying to use mod_rewrite unless I'm entirely misunderstanding your question.  But it sounds like you are using SVNParentPath and are having trouble figuring out how to configure the authz settings for all the repositories.

You have a couple of options.

**Use one authz file**

You can actually generate a single authz file and specify which repositories the rules apply to.  The syntax is of the form `[repos-name:path]` (as you can find in the [Path-Based Authorization section of the Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)).  One disadvantage of this is that if you have a lot of repositories and a lot of paths with rules it can slow things down.  Which it sounds like you've run into.  One thing that can help mitigate this some is using the following configuration

```
SVNPathAuthz short_circuit
```

[SVNPathAuthz](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.mod_dav_svn.conf.html) controls how requests for paths other than the URI are authorized when other paths need to be accessed than the URI of the request (e.g. log, commit, etc).  The default behavior is to issue a sub-request.  This generates a new GET request in httpd and sends it through all of the authorization infrastructure for httpd.  However, in almost all cases this is not needed since the only authorization configuration that can vary with the path under the Location being used to serve SVN is the mod_authz_svn configuration.  short_circuit, tells Subversion to avoid all of this and simply send the authorization info straight to mod_authz_svn who provides the answer directly limiting the delay.

That may still not be enough so there are a couple of alternatives, but you'll need at least 1.7 to use them.

**AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile**

[Subversion 1.7 added a new configuration directive](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#per-repos-authz) that lets you specify a path relative to the conf subdirectory of the repository.  For instance if you have a repo named foo you can put the authz file in /path/to/foo/conf/authz and then set the following configuration value:

```
AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile authz
```

The directive prior to 1.7 that was used AuthzSVNAccessFile was relative to the server root path.

**In Repository Authz***

[Subversion 1.8 allows you to store the authz file in the repository itself](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#in-repo-authz).  So for instance if you committed the file in the repo in a directory named conf as the file authz then you'd do:

```
AuthzSVNAccessFile ^/authz
```

The ^/ syntax is replaced with the full path to the repository.

You probably want to read the details on the linked release notes for 1.8 if you decide to use this.

Comment: Thanks, `SVNPathAuthz`plus `AuthzSVNReposRelativeAccessFile` was what I needed.